# How to load local files in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

So I started working with Keras and I was trying out the `lstm_text_generation` from the examples. The problem is that have a text file on local directory but the `get_file` method has a `origin` parameter which requires a file which is hosted somewhere.

I wanted to know if a local file can be used or I have to host the file online?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of `get_file` is downloading a file over the network.
If you want to access something on your file system, you don't need it.

In the case of the text generator, just use something like:

```
text = open("localfile.txt").read().lower()
```

and delete the line with `path = get_line(...)`

Answer (score 1):

If I have to read from a file (`someDataFile.txt`) into a numpy array `X_train` (to be used in some task by a Keras model) then I can do so like this -

```
X_train = np.genfromtxt(r"C:\Users\tauseef\Desktop\keras\tutorials\features\someDataFile.txt",delimiter=" ")
```